# How to make forward button work on this example using HTML5 history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

In this example we manage to make back button work but forward button seem to be a problem, when forward button is pressed,  `#modal` should reappear but it did not. Any idea to fix it?

```js
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
  $('#modal').hide();
});

$(".view").click(function() {
  history.pushState(null, null, null);
  $("#modal").show();
});
```

```css
#modal {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="view">Click</button>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

[Here is JSBin](http://jsbin.com/helivu)

Thanks!

Comment: What is history.pushState(null, null, null); doing? I see no back button or forward button. Not clear what you are doing from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pushing all `null` onto the history you aren't coupling the state / view of the page in any way. Are you aware that the `popstate` event is also fired when you move forward along the stack too?

Most people tend to use relative URLs (or fragments) known as *"routing"* to resolve history / content but you can also use the first parameter of `pushState` to add data - how you manage this mechanism on a larger scale is out of scope but a simple example would be as follows:

```js
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    var state = history.state || {};
    state.openModal ? $('#modal').show() : $('#modal').hide();
});

$(".view").click(function(){
    $('#modal').show();
    history.pushState({ openModal: true });
});
```

[**» demo**](http://jsbin.com/siguqufono)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "hash" instead of "history"

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
  if(location.hash.indexOf('#modal') != -1)
      $('#modal').show();
  else
    $('#modal').hide();
});

$(".view").click(function(){
  location.hash ='#modal';
  $("#modal").show();
});
```

This is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/sazobireyu)